# Display a picture from MS Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, picturebox

Good Day! I am currently building a student management information system in VB.Net with Access Database. All Things are working perfectly except this one:

Displaying an Image of the current logged in user from it's Picture column.

All text fields are displaying all the values assigned in my database depending on the current user logged in. Here is my code for displaying the user's info:

```
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\Data\Db\Faculty.mdb;")
    Dim dr1 As OleDbDataReader
    Dim com As New OleDbCommand


    com.CommandText = "select [Username],[Fname],[Lname],[Mname],[NickName],[Birthday],[Adds],[City],[CounPC],[Gender],[Religion],[Citizenship],[Contact],[stats],[Fathername],[Mothername],[FMAddress],[CollCourse],[VocCourse],[ElemEd],[ElemGrad],[HighEd],[HighGrad],[CollegeEd],[CollegeGrad],[VocationalCourse],[Skills],[Company],[Company1],[Position],[Position1],[YrStart],[YrStart1] from Personal where Username = '" & mainForm.TSUname.Text & "'"
    com.Connection = cn
    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Open()

    ' Username
    Dim Username As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@Username", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
    Username.Value = mainForm.TSUname.Text.ToString
    com.Parameters.Add(Username)

    dr1 = com.ExecuteReader
    If dr1.Read Then
        If dr1(1) = My.Settings.CurrentUserName.ToString Then
            ' Personal Information
            tbFname.Text = dr1(1)
            tbLname.Text = dr1(2)
            tbMname.Text = dr1(3)
            lblNickname.Text = dr1(4) & "!"
            tbBday.Text = dr1(5)
            tbAdd.Text = dr1(6)
            tbCity.Text = dr1(7)
            tbCountry.Text = dr1(8)
            tbGender.Text = dr1(9)
            tbReligion.Text = dr1(10)
            tbCitizenship.Text = dr1(11)
            tbContact.Text = dr1(12)
            tbStatus.Text = dr1(13)
            ' Parents
            tbFather.Text = dr1(14)
            tbMother.Text = dr1(15)
            tbAddress.Text = dr1(16)
            'Educational Background
            tbCollCourse.Text = dr1(17)
            tbVocCourse.Text = dr1(18)
            tbElemEd.Text = dr1(19)
            tbElemGrad.Text = dr1(20)
            tbHSEd.Text = dr1(21)
            tbHSGrad.Text = dr1(22)
            tbCollED.Text = dr1(23)
            tbColGrad.Text = dr1(24)
            tbVocational.Text = dr1(25)
            tbSkill.Text = dr1(26)
            ' Employment Background
            tbCompany.Text = dr1(27)
            tbCompany1.Text = dr1(28)
            tbPosition.Text = dr1(29)
            tbPosition1.Text = dr1(30)
            tbStart.Text = dr1(31)
            tbStart1.Text = dr1(32)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Input", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("UserID is Wrong", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
```

I want to put the user's picture too in my `PictureBox`. But how? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: in saving you will need to convert the image to a byte array, then convert it back when reading a record.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/217928/1070452) does that very thing, for C# (basically image-> memstream -> byte() ).  You also need to implement SQL params to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway, Do i have to copy his/her code and convert it to vb?

Comment: I would use a JPG as the base rather than a BMP - it will result in smaller output.  Otherwise, you can use the last 4 lines of link code to see the steps (do them in reverse to save to the DB). Here is a VB version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6861581/1070452

Comment: oh thanks. im gonna do have a try to see if it works. thanks

Comment: Saving images themselves inside an .mdb or .accdb is generally a bad idea.  It's very easy to bloat the file and even if you are careful you run the risk of bumping into Access's 2GB max db size limit.  The more common approach is to save the images to disk and store only the path (or enough info to recreate the path) within the Access database file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Followed the majority and just upload the image on a specific directory and then store its path in my database. Then, I will just get the path whenever i want to retrieve the image and assign it to my picturebox's imagePath property.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who helped!